# How to find the wsdl class?

Tags: apex, wsdl

How can I come to know that a class is generated from wsld or not ?

Please provide me an answer . Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Forum etiquette doesn't really require you to use  (albeit polite) exhortations like "please provide me an answer" - simply posting your question, as you have seen will get you an answer if one is to be had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't modify the class comment. Salesforce insert comment on top of the page as shown below

[image]

Comment: @Anon Please mark answer as correct to help others.